# How to change value for a variable in Javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

Please check the below code and let me know what I have missed.

```js
function Student() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.type = "Regular";
}

Student.prototype.changeType = function(givenType) {
  this.type = givenType;
}

Student.prototype.changeType('Part-Time');

var William = new Student();

console.log(William.type); //Regular
```

The console expectation is `Part-Time`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** If you want to set the type for all current and future instances, you can try storing all the instances. You will have to update all new students as you add them. JavaScript does not know how to get all objects, current and future, just by the class name.

```js
function Student() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.type = "Regular";
  Student.instances.push(this); // Add
}
Student.prototype.changeType = function(givenType) {
  this.type = givenType;
}

Student.instances = []; // Keep track
Student.changeAllTypes = function(type) {
  Student.instances.forEach(function(instance) {
    instance.changeType(type);
  });
};

var William = new Student();

Student.changeAllTypes('Part-Time');

console.log(William.type); // Part-Time
```

The proper way to do this is to just pass in the appropriate parameters during instantiation of the object.

```js
function Student(name, type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
}

var william = new Student('William', 'Part-Time');

console.log(william.type); // Part-Time
```

---

The prototype is not the same as an instance.

```js
function Student() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.type = "Regular";
}

Student.prototype.changeType = function(givenType) {
  this.type = givenType;
}

Student.prototype.changeType('Part-Time');

var William = new Student();

console.log(Student.prototype.type); // Part-Time
```

If you want to change the type, you need to set the property to just William.

```js
function Student () {
    this.name = "John";
    this.type = "Regular";
}

Student.prototype.changeType = function (givenType) {
   this.type = givenType;
}

var William = new Student();

William.changeType('Part-Time');

console.log(William.type); // Part-Time
```

Or you could create a native ES6 class, which makes this easier.

```js
class Student {
  constructor(name = 'John', type = 'Regular') {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
  setType(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  getType() {
    return this.type;
  }
}

var william = new Student();

william.setType('Part-Time');

console.log(william.getType()); // Part-Time
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actually I am trying to override the existing method in the object or props. Can you please advise how can achieve that?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan so, reflection?

Answer (score 1):

JS only checks the next level up the prototype chain if a value for a property hasn’t been set on the object itself.

You are calling `changeType` on the prototype, not on the object itself.

The constructor sets the property on the object itself.

Calling `William.changeType("Part-Time")` would have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actually I am trying to override the existing method in the object or props.

Can you please advice how can achieve that?

Comment: If you want to override the method then you need to assign a new function to the changeType property

Comment: I have tried below but still not working.
```
function Student () {
    this.name = "John";
    this.type = "Regular";

    this.changeType = function () {
        console.log('Part-Time');
    }
}

Student.prototype.changeType= function (givenType) {
   this.type = givenType;
}

var William = new Student();

William.changeType('Part-Time');

console.log(William.type);
```

Comment: What do you expect? You overrode the changeType method so it called console.log instead of changing the type!

Comment: @Quentine, exactly. I want to change the existing function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a structure that has a method that refers to the instance *(this)* `constructor`'s `prototype`. Then the next `new` instance will have the property, as called by the previously called instance method.

```js
function Student(name = null, type = null){
  this.changeName = name=>{
    this.constructor.prototype.name = name;
    return this;
  }
  this.changeType = type=>{
    this.constructor.prototype.type = type;
    return this;
  }
  if(name !== null)this.changeName(name);
  if(type !== null)this.changeType(type);
}
const john = new Student('John', 'Part-Time');
console.log(john.name+' -> '+john.type);
const bob = new Student('Bob');
console.log(bob.name+' -> '+bob.type);
const joe = new Student('Joe', 'Full-Time');
console.log(joe.name+' -> '+joe.type);
const dan = new Student('Dan');
console.log(dan.name+' -> '+dan.type);
```